# Jaro-Winkler's difference between packages

Tags: r, fuzzy-comparison, stringdist, record-linkage

I am using fuzzy matching to clean up medication data input by users, and I am using Jaro-Winkler's distance. I was testing which package with Jaro-Winkler's distance was faster when I noticed the default settings do not give identical values. Can anyone help me understand where the difference comes from? Example:

```
library(RecordLinkage)
library(stringdist)

jarowinkler("advil", c("advi", "advill", "advil", "dvil", "sdvil"))
# [1] 0.9600000 0.9666667 1.0000000 0.9333333 0.8666667
1- stringdist("advil", c("advi", "advill", "advil", "dvil", "sdvil"), method = "jw")
# [1] 0.9333333 0.9444444 1.0000000 0.9333333 0.8666667
```

I am assuming it has to do with the weights, and I know I am using the defaults on both. However, if someone with more experience could shed light on what's going on, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Documentation:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/RecordLinkage.pdf

Comment: The r argument was not immediately clear to me either. I am guessing it is referring to the radius it is "allowed" to search for a transposition (aka, fixing transposed letters to find a match).  E.g., if I am comparing words "form" and "from", the "r" and "o" are transposed. In this case, the r = .5 would allow a search radius for transpositions of 2 (.5 * 4 letter word). At least, that is what makes sense to me.

Comment: it makes sense, but I didn't see it mentioned in the paper....

Comment: I think you're right. Spotted in the source (and confirmed by my broken German + Google Translate) [here](https://github.com/cran/RecordLinkage/blob/master/src/jarowinkler.c#L8-L19)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tucked away in the documentation for `stringdist` is the following:

> The Jaro-Winkler distance (`method=jw`, `0<p<=0.25`) adds a correction term to the Jaro-distance. It is defined as `d − l · p · d`, where `d` is the Jaro-distance. Here, `l` is obtained by counting, from the start of the input strings, after how many characters the first character mismatch between the two strings occurs, with a maximum of four. **The factor `p` is a penalty factor, which in the work of Winkler is often chosen 0.1.**

However, in `stringdist::stringdist`, `p = 0` by default. Hence:

```
1 - stringdist("advil", c("advi", "advill", "advil", "dvil", "sdvil"), 
               method = "jw", p = .1)
# [1] 0.9600000 0.9666667 1.0000000 0.9333333 0.8666667
```

In fact that value is [hard-coded in the source of `RecordLinkage::jarowinkler`](https://github.com/cran/RecordLinkage/blob/master/src/jarowinkler.c#L135).